# OpenSSL: Bad Record MAC on TLS Heart Beat

Tags: tls, cryptography, openssl, heartbleed

I am trying to see the heartbleed bug in action with my OpenSSL server application.

My server uses the OpenSSL library - openssl-1.0.1b

I successfully connect with s_client (openssl-1.0.1b) to my server. The SSL Handshake is through.

Now, I type 'B' to send in a encrypted Heartbeat to the server. But the server closes the connection with Alert. The s_client dumps the following info:

> HEARTBEATING
>
> > > TLS 1.0  [length 0025], HeartbeatRequest
>
> SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert bad record mac:s3_pkt.c:1256:SSL alert number 20

However if I were to type in some other data, it gets treated as application data and is processed by my server.

And another thing to note is that the same s_client successsfully exchanges heartbeats with *www.yahoo.com*

Why could my server not accept heartbeat message even though in server hello it mentioned that it supports that extension?

**Edit(Update)**

One thing that I hadn't realized was that the SSL library was actually TurboSSL, Cavium's port of OpenSSL to use the hardware accelarator. With this I see the error that I mentioned.

When I use the plain OpenSSl library, it worked fine!. Heartbeats were being sent from server.

Comment: Have you checked whether the heartbeat functionality is enabled by default in the server you are talking about ?

Comment: @Arun,the OpenSSL library is used as is. By default heartbeat is enabled, ins't? And also, in the server hello, server does indicate that it is OK for doing heartbeat exchanges.

Comment: @Arun. Sorry. My statement is not entirely true. I use TurboSSL which is essentially OpenSSl extended t use the Cavium accelerator.